# How to show that $\Phi^{-1}(1-x) =O(\sqrt{\log{x^{-1}}})$

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality, quantile

In the middle of some proof, I have faced an expression $\Phi^{-1}(1-x) =O(\sqrt{\log{x^{-1}}})$, where $\Phi(\cdot)^{-1}$ is a quantile function of the standard normal distribution and $x \in (0,1)$.

Can someone help me how to prove this or give me a quick reference?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you include the definition of the function $\Phi(x)$?

Comment: In the Landau notation $O\left(\sqrt{\log\frac{1}{x}}\right)$ are we assuming that $x\to 0$ or $x\to 1$ ?

Comment: Re: Semiclassical...
Sorry about that. $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the cdf of the standard normal distribution.

Comment: Re: Jack D'aurizio...
Yes, we are interested in the tail rate of those quantile sequences. We are interested in the case of  $x\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: There exist very tight bounds for such tails due to the fact that the erf integral admits a fast converging representation in terms of a continued fraction, you can find it by googling "Mills ratio" and "continued fraction", for instance. For our purposes, it is enough to isolate the main term of the asymptotics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that $X\sim N(0,1)$, we have:
$$\int_{w}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{w^2}{2}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-xw-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)dx\leq\frac{1}{w\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{w^2}{2}\right)$$
and, by assuming $w\gg 1$:
$$\int_{w}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{w^2}{2}\right)\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}e^{-xw}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)dx\geq\frac{w^2-1}{w^3\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{w^2}{2}\right),$$
hence:
$$\Phi^{-1}(1-x)=\Theta\left(\sqrt{-\log x}\right)$$
as long as $x\to 0$.
$$\Phi^{-1}(1-x)\approx\sqrt{W\left(\frac{1}{2\pi x^2}\right)}$$
is an even more precise approximation in terms of the Lambert W-function.

Comment: Got it! Thanks so much.

Comment: @user165795: I politely ask you to accept my answer, if you think it is satisfactory.

Comment: My apologies. I'm a newbie here and didn't know the protocol well. :)